# how to access parents of view controller and properly dismiss self and self.parent?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

In `MyViewController`, I ask the user to select a person from address book: (on a button click)

```
peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:peoplePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

If user selects a person with more than one phone number, I present a new UITableViewController which allows the user to select one of the phone numbers:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    // ...
    next = [[ChoosePersonPhoneViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped personPhoneInfoArray:personPhoneInfos];
    [peoplePicker pushViewController:next animated:YES];
    // ...
}
```

When the user selects a phone number, I would like to bring that phone number back to original ViewController and close both `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and `ChoosePersonPhoneViewController`.

Two questions:

- How do I close both view controllers from within `ChoosePersonPhoneViewController`?
- How do I access `MyViewController` from within `ChoosePersonPhoneViewController`?

My guess would be that:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)self.navigationController;
MyViewController *nsvc = (MyViewController *)peoplePicker.presentingViewController;
```

I have tried many combinations using `parentViewController` and `presentingViewController` and `popViewController` / `dismissViewController`, but can't really figure it out - I keep getting exceptions which show my lack of understanding of the view controller hierarchy. I would appreciate some pointers or at least RTFM links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your second question answered, your first question becomes easy.  In ChoosePersonPhoneViewController, have a property of the same class as myViewController named parent, and when you allocate ChoosePersonPhoneViewController from myViewController, set it to self, much like you set the delegate to self.  Once parent is set, you can call methods in parent from the child object.

Answer (score 1):

Handling changes, actions, or user interaction in other views is the essential use case of [delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).  The best practice is to have the first view controller be the delegate of `NewSettingsViewController`, and then as the user chooses one of the phone numbers, it calls certain methods on its delegate to notify it of the final choice.  Typically  the delegate can determine if it is satisfied with the results it gets and can then dismiss any controllers that are no longer needed.

Other options for keeping values/state in sync between views are:

- [Key-Value Observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) - best used for data
- `NSNotification`s sent through [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - best used for actions

Answer (score 1):

You should try on your `ChoosePersonPhoneViewController` to access the `presentingViewController` which apple doc states that:

> this property holds the view controller presenting the nearest
>   ancestor

So you can try something `[ChoosePersonPhoneViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` (note this method is deprecated in iOS 6).